# eval() does not assign variable at runtime

Tags: python, string, eval

I use `eval()` to assign a list to a var:

```
eval('mylist = [1,2,3]')
```

but when I run it , I got a SyntaxError. What's wrong with it? If I cannot do assignment in the `eval()`, how do I assign a var in the runtime.

Comment: On a totally unrelated note, you're probably better off using either `locals()`, `globals()`, or for the really daring, a dictionary.

Comment: @Snakes and Coffee: Now I have learned these two functions. Here is my situation: I want to create a new member var in a class. How do I implement it ?

Comment: you could do `setattr(<your object>,'mylist',[1,2,3])`

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee much better, `<your object>` would be `self` if this is in `__init__` for example

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `exec` for statements:

```
>>> exec 'lis = [1,2,3]'
>>> lis
[1, 2, 3]
```

`eval` works only on expressions, like `2*2`,`4+5` etc

`eval` and `exec` are okay if the string is coming from a known source, but don't use them if the string is coming from an unknown source(user input).

Read : [Be careful with exec and eval in Python](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/)

Comment: Not that this is `exec('mylist = [1, 2, 3]')` in python 3

Comment: Insert obligatory "be careful with `exec`, it can be dangerous" here