# Use loop to name variables

Tags: python

So I essentially want to know how to do this in python:

```
X = int(input("How many students do you want to add? "))
for X:
    studentX = str(input("Student Name: "))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: *Short answer* : you can't do that easily, but you can use a dictionary.

Comment: If you really wanted to do this,  you could start hacking `globals()`, but that's a __very__ bad idea

Comment: @C.B.: well, you can, with globals at least, but you *really don't want to do that*. Because next thing you know you want to address those variables and you'd have to generate those names again. And again, and again. While with a list or dictionary, you just don't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't. You'd use a list instead:

```
how_many = int(input("How many students do you want to add? "))
students = []
for i in range(how_many):
    students.append(input("Student Name: "))
```

Generally speaking, you [keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Comment: If I can use myself as an example, one of my first professional projects in Python involved getting file size information from a couple hundred machines. We were concerned that a purge process wasn't running correctly. I used `globals()` hacking to pipe them all into dictionaries named after each file, with the key as the machine I was polling. This means I have NO idea now how to maintain that script, and God Help Me if I ever have to repair it for any reason

Answer (score 2):

I upvoted Martijn's answer, but if you need something similar to a variable name, that you can call with student1 to studentX, you can use an object:

```
how_many = int(input("How many students do you want to add? "))
students = {}
for i in range(how_many):
    students["student{}".format(i+1)] = input("Student Name: ")
```

I'm not gonna suggest the [`exec`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230005/eval-does-not-assign-variable-at-runtime?rq=1) solution...

Comment: Note that `i` starts at `0`, not `1`, so you get `student0` through to `student<X-1>`.

Comment: Surely you meant `i + 1`, not `-`.

Comment: Sure, embarrassing. I also accepted a suggested edit by @s16h